# Error with Python multi-processing when used inside a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, joblib

I'm running into `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'proc/69/task/64` exception while using python multiprocessing & joblib inside a docker container. (I have 100 batches that I'm running on 5 processes during a single app run)

It doesn't happen all the time but after a couple of runs the error shows up. Tried switching between processes and threads but no help.

Does anyone have any idea of where I should look to solve this problem?

Comment: Create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your chances of getting help.